# lrzip compression does not shrink random data

Tags: compression, archive

I'm trying to shrink down some big files around 3.0 GB each and I decided to use lrzip after seeing a few benchmarks and such however is it something I'm doing wrong or something as whenever I run

```
lrzip -z -N -20 -p 9 -U filename
```

it finishes but my filesize does not change at all.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.0G May 31 13:58 random.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.0G Jun  4 21:40 random.data.lrz
```

any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Random data is not compressible. Try benchmarking with some real data. But remember, some file formats (particularly video and image) already contain compressed data so they will not compress much further.